# Customization for VersionDiff.aspx in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, templates, customization

I have a Wiki site, and on wiki pages if I select to check history of pages it displays in the Left action panel Version and date as hyperlinks.
It uses SharePoint's Diff iterator, I want to do a bit of customization here, along with date I want to display field values too.

How can I do that?
Thanks,
Azra

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you have to customize otherwise non-customizable pages, is to use a HTTP Module. 
Override the EndRequest event and redirect to a custom page of yours. Which can be a copy of the original, with your custom modifications.